# Input String not in Correct format error in c# DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

'Am getting this error in the following code:

```
string QtyVal = MatCompDtlDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
decimal Result = (Convert.ToDecimal(QtyVal)) / 999;
if (Result == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Quantity value can not be null");
}
```

Comment: What is the vaule of `QtyVal` exactly?

Comment: What Culture you using by the way?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what is the value of `QtyVal` exactly but you can use [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method first to check your string is convertable to decimal or not.

> Converts the string representation of a number to its Decimal
>   equivalent using the specified style and culture-specific format. A
>   return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

```
string QtyVal = MatCompDtlDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
decimal d;
if(Decimal.TryParse(QtyVal, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{
   d= (Convert.ToDecimal(QtyVal)) / 999;
}
```

> Its 0000 or 00.00

Both

```
Convert.ToDecimal(0000)
Convert.ToDecimal(00.00)
```

works on me. Beucase my [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `tr-TR` and [`NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `.` and most probably your culture doesn't have a dot as `NumberGroupSeparator` but since you didn't tell us what your culture is, we never know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `(Convert.ToDecimal(QtyVal)) / 999` to a decimal:

```
 decimal result = (decimal)((Convert.ToDecimal(QtyVal)) / 999);
```

Comment: True. I probably should have read the question more carefully. If the converted value is 0, and you're dividing it by 999, will it throw an exception?

Comment: I figured not; I was just confirming. */new to this whole programming thing.*

Answer (score 0):

I checked up the value in QtyVal variable which was "" for both 0000 and 00.00 so instead of converting it to decimal, I checked it for null in my if condition and it worked.